# Conditional Custom Buttons

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I was just asked to combine 2 buttons that open 2 separate visual force pages.  So my idea was to create one button(obviously). Is it possible to after that ask the user which record they want to create?

On `Opp Parts` sits two buttons(visualforce pages, with controllers), and depending on which one you click it will create the `Sample` or `EVB`,  Now they don't want to have two buttons  They want one button. When you click the one button they want users to have to choose which one they want.  How could I go about doing this?

Don't think I need this, but might help visualize it better

[image]

Comment: Somewhere along the line they're going to have to choose, right? Why not make it right up front where it's really simple? Users... Anyway, you can make a single button that pops up a [jQuery Dialog] (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)  that will have "Do you want to create Sample Request or EVB Request?" and then it will have the same old 2 buttons in it.

Comment: I was thinking give the user 3 options Sample,EVB, and Both. After that I can have conditions that will call certain controllers, am I thinking of it wrong?

Comment: If they want to combine the functions as well as the buttons, you could make a little wizard type screen. So they press the "one button" and go to a new VF page that asks "Sample or EVB or Both". Then, if you chose sample or both it goes to the sample screen. if you chose EVB it goes to the EVB screen. if you chose both, after the sample screen, you go to the evb screen. Probably more complicated to say than to do.

Comment: I'm not combining the functions just the buttons

Comment: @Dominic, write that up as an answer